zip files using fflate into blob for download
I'm writing an extension that downloads images, there are quite a lot and to not crash the browser I decided to zip them, I first used JSZip and it worked like a charm, took me 5 min to write but was too slow for my likings, whereas fflate...
I'm following the documentation for adding files
console.log('file.size', file.size);
const nonStreamingFile = new fflate.ZipPassThrough(filename);
zip.add(nonStreamingFile);
const content = new Uint8Array(await file.arrayBuffer());
nonStreamingFile.push(content, true);

file is xhr.response and xhr an XMLHttpRequest instance
I then put the zip into a blob, following this
async function getZipContent(zip) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const chunks = [];

        zip.ondata = (err, chunk, final) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            if (chunk) chunks.push(...chunk);
            if (final) resolve(chunks);
        };

        zip.end();
    });
}

async function downloadZip(zip) {
    const content = await getZipContent(zip);
    console.log('content', content);
    const blob = new Blob(content, { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

    const a = document.createElement('a');
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = blobUrl;
    a.download = 'out.zip';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
}

I modified a bit getZipContent, I flattened all chunks because I want an array and not an array of arrays (which, I can confirm, was what I was getting without the "...")
In my test case, file.size is 358238 but content is of length 127, the downloaded zip can sometimes be opened when I change some things around but the image is 0 byte, otherwise it's damaged and cannot be opened with WinRAR

I tried swapping zip.add(nonStreamingFile); and nonStreamingFile.push(content, true); but I get Uncaught (in promise) Error: no stream handler

I tried wrapping the content from getZipContent in a new Uint8Array but it does nothing

I tried replacing application/octet-stream with application/zip but it does nothing


To be fair, the main problem is probably around zip.add(nonStreamingFile); more than anything, since all I'm getting is 117 bytes in getZipContent... i'm not sure
I'm out of ideas and patience to be honest, but I really want to give fflate a try

What is the size of content here:  const content = new Uint8Array(await file.arrayBuffer()); ?

IIRC, you should wait for a few seconds before calling revokeObjectURL.

@James I can confirm they are definitely not empty, I simply console.log'ed them, they are proper images

@woxxom when I was working with JSZip the code from the creation of the a element was the same and there was no problem, the zip did contain all the images
Also, the content from getZipContent is already 117 bytes only so the downloading of the zip is not the problem here, it's the creation process
